# Input username from user and use it to delete a row in mysql using java(JDBC)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

```
System.out.println("Enter name of site or app");
app_name= sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter username of account to remove");
user_name= sc.nextLine();
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("delete from "+app_name+" where USERNAME='haridinesh00'");
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Here instead of haridinesh00 I want to replace it with user_name. But since user_name is of type String, the value is enclosed in double quotes. Sql only allows single quotes.

Comment: _"But since user_name is of type String, the value is enclosed in double quotes."_ That makes no sense, that is not how Java strings work. Double quotes enclose strings in **source code**, the actual string is not enclosed in double quotes. However you should use prepared statements instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM "+app_name+" WHERE USERNAME = ?";
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) 
pstmt.setString(1, user_name);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Note that in this way, you do not have to enclose your string within the single quote; the database driver will take care of it for you.

Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to learn more about `PreparedStatement`.

However, if you still want to do it in your way, do it as follows:

```
conn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM "+app_name+" WHERE USERNAME = '" + user_name + "'");
```

or even better as follows:

```
conn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM "+app_name+" WHERE USERNAME = " + pstmt.enquoteLiteral(user_name));
```

Comment: conn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM "+app_name+" WHERE USERNAME = '" + user_name + "'"); This worked, thanks.